# Proposed edit makes no sense?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I've got an [edit rejected](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/438652), which is ok, but I'm a bit puzzled by the rejection comment.

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I found the edited answer as the highest quality, as it uses an existing feature of rsync rather than proposing workarounds or wrappers. The answer however, lacked the context information that would make it self-contained for future readers. Which is what I added.

The answer author seems to be inactive for a several months. So not making the edit now, would leave the answer in a shabby state indefinitely.

I don't understand why this "makes no sense". And I surely would find it unfair to the original answer author to post my proposed edits as a new answer.

If a new answer would be proper by the community standards, I'll roll with it. But I just wanted to have a second opinion, especially to know better in future edits.

Comment: You should have just posted your edit as a full answer.